# PHP foreach in html tags

Tags: php, html

I am pulling data out of a DB and then displaying it on my html page. I had thought that my code below would work and it does as far as getting the data and placing it into variables. It breaks down when trying to inject the variable into a html tag. I had also, probably incorrectly, assume that by placing my html tags inside a php foreach loop that it would dynamically create all the tags needed depending on the number of rows returned. I need the foreach as the data is an array so to get each record I need to look through the array.

I have this code placed on in my body tag where I want the elements to be placed.

PHP functions in body tag above section where elements are to be.

```html
                        <?php
                            function db_connect() {

                                // Define connection as a static variable, to avoid connecting more than once 
                                static $connection;

                                // Try and connect to the database, if a connection has not been established yet
                                if(!isset($connection)) {
                                     // Load configuration as an array. Use the actual location of your configuration file
                                    $config = parse_ini_file('\assets\con_config.ini'); 
                                    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost',$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['dbname']);
                                }

                                // If connection was not successful, handle the error
                                if($connection === false) {
                                    // Handle error - notify administrator, log to a file, show an error screen, etc.
                                    return mysqli_connect_error(); 
                                }
                                return $connection;
                            }

                            function db_query($query) {
                                // Connect to the database
                                $connection = db_connect();

                                // Query the database
                                $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

                                return $result;
                            }

                            function db_select($query) {
                                $rows = array();
                                $result = db_query($query);

                                // If query failed, return `false`
                                if($result === false) {
                                    return false;
                                }

                                // If query was successful, retrieve all the rows into an array
                                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                    $rows[] = $row;
                                }
                                return $rows;
                            }

                            $rows = db_select("select CONCAT_WS(' ', fname, mname, lname) as author_name, title, image_location, rating, review, (Select mid(date_reviewed,1,2) from reviews where reviews.book_id = books.id) as day, (Select mid(date_reviewed,4,3) from reviews where reviews.book_id = books.id) as month, (Select mid(date_reviewed,8,2) from reviews where reviews.book_id = books.id) as year, sellers_site, twitter_site, fb_site, twitter_id, fb_id, genre from authors, books, book_genre, book_link, reviews, social_media where books.author_id = authors.id and book_genre.book_id = books.id and book_link.book_id = books.id and reviews.book_id = books.id and social_media.author_id = authors.id group by ireviews.reviews.date_reviewed ASC");
                            if($rows === false) {
                                $error = db_error();
                                // Handle error - inform administrator, log to file, show error page, etc.
                            }

                                //foreach($rows as $value){

                                    //echo $value['author_name'] . "<br />\n";
                                    //echo $value['title'] . "<br />\n";
                                    //echo $value['rating'] . "<br />\n";
                                //}

                        ?>
                        
                        <? php foreach($rows as $value); ?>
```

HTML part for displaying the returned data.

```html
<? php foreach($rows as $value); ?>
                    
                    <div class="block">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-8">
                                <div class="widget-block">
                                    <input id="rate1" value="<?php echo $value['rating']?>" type="number" class="rating" data-max="5" data-min="0"  data-size="sm" data-show-clear="false" readOnly="readOnly">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $value['sellers_site']?>" target="#"><img class="img-responsive wow fadeInLeftBig animated" data-wow-duration="1.5s" src="<?php echo $value['$image_location']?>" alt="<?php echo $value['$author_name']?>"></a>
                                    <br>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $value['sellers_site']?>" class="btn btn-success" target="_blank">Buy this book</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-8">
                                <div class="section-sub-title">
                                    <article class="section-title-body white">
                                        <h1 class="head-title">Author: <span><?php echo $value['$author_name']?> -</span> <?php echo $value['$title']?></h1>
                                        <span class="point-line hidden-xs hidden-sm"></span>
                                        <p>
                                            <?php echo $value['$review']?>
                                        </p>
                                    </article>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>   
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: `<? php` tell us that actually reads as `<?php` in your real code.

Comment: Use `<?php foreach($rows as $value) { ?>`

Comment: and guess what this does `foreach($rows as $value);` <<< right there. Would you like a detailed explanation for it, or would you just like to grab an answer and go?

Comment: I guess nobody (below) wants to "explain" the semi-colon in this `foreach($rows as $value);` or knows what it really does and won't throw an error for it neither. There "is" a reason.

Comment: Always looking to expand my understanding Fred -ii- :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You had a space between "<" and `php` keywords in your `foreach`, also you didn't have opening bracket or colon on the end of the same line. Try something like:

```
<?php foreach($rows as $value): ?>
    ....
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip but still nothing. copied in the tag from your post just to make sure.

Comment: I was being a dummie. I was running that in my HTML file. I renamed it to PHP and it is at least semi working.

Comment: Now the issue seems to be with the way the variable is in the html tags. The only variable that is rendering is the first one in each iteration of the loop  value="<?php echo $value['rating']?>" after that all the other variables are coming up with a undefined error.

Answer (score 2):

> I had also, probably incorrectly, assume that by placing my html tags
>   inside a php foreach loop that it would dynamically create all the
>   tags needed depending on the number of rows returned.

That's exactly how it works, except for a few sintax mistakes you made:

1:

```
<? php
```

should be

```
<?php
```

2:

```
foreach($rows as $value); ?>
```

should be this

```
foreach($rows as $value){ ?>
```

Also, if you're using a somewhat modern version of PHP (5.4+) you can use the short php tags and short output.

This

```
value="<?php echo $value['rating']?>"
```

equals to

```
value="<?=$value['rating']?>"
```

Comment: Be aware of short tags syntax: `<?=`, as it's only available in PHP 5.4+.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your foreach to:

```
foreach($rows as $value) { ?>
```